# How to control tab button cursor pointing in horizontal direction

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4.1, extjs5

In EXTJS how we can control tab cursor movement in form page , currently I have textfields in formpanel and when pressing tab button its moving in vertical direction I want to move that in horizontal direction

Comment: Can you post some sample code? Normally tab order is defined by the natural order of the items and the specific layout type you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can use tabIndex

Answer (score 0):

It's handled in way how the component is being added in the container component.

Try using tab Index config - https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-tabIndex

Share Sencha fiddle with similar layout

Comment: Tab index is a good quick-fix but it might be hard to maintain later on, if there are too many components with explicit tab index.